# extract two hashtags next to each other in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm analyzing twitter data and would like to extract all the hashtags in tweets. I used to extract hashtags like this:

```
tweet = 'I like #apple #orange'
str_extract_all(tweet,"#\\S+")
```

This works in most situations. But sometimes two hashtags are next to each other.

```
tweet = 'I like #apple#orange'
str_extract_all(tweet,"#\\S+")
```

what I got is this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "#apple#orange"
```

Does anyone know how I can properly extract hashtags when they are either separated or next to each other?

Comment: Can you check your package versison.  I am not able to reproduce `[1] "#apple"  "#orange"`

Comment: Try using `#[^#\\s]+`

Comment: Just use `str_extract_all(tweet,"#\\w+")` to extract the texts like in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overmatching with `\S` because that will match a non whitespace character and a `#` as well.

You could use a [negated character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) class to not match a whitespace char as well as not a `#`

```
#[^#\\s]+
```

Your code might look like

```
tweet = 'I like #apple#orange'
str_extract_all(tweet,"#[^#\\s]+")
```

Result

```
[[1]]
[1] "#apple"  "#orange
```

[R demo](https://ideone.com/CWiRLf)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this simple expression might work:

```
#([^#\s]+)
```

which excludes spaces and `#`s after the first `#`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h05HzG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Another(arguably less concise) `base` possibility:

```
gsub("([a-z](?=#))(#\\w)","\\1 \\2",
     strsplit(tweet," (?=#+)",perl = TRUE)[[1]][2], perl=TRUE)
[1] "#apple #orange"
```

If you need them separated:

```
 strsplit(gsub("([a-z](?=#))(#\\w)","\\1 \\2",
      strsplit(tweet," (?=#+)",perl = TRUE)[[1]][2], perl=TRUE),
      " ")
[[1]]
[1] "#apple"  "#orange"
```